# How to write the path to the form through a variable?

Tags: ms-access, vba

There is a code:

```
 Private Sub Button0_Click()
        Dim nameField  As String
        nameField = "Field0"

        Dim nameForm  As String
        nameForm = "Form1"

        ' DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm nameForm

        Forms![Form1](nameField).Text = "Message for `Form1`"

End Sub
```

In this code, you can access the form field through the variable "nameField".
Line

```
    Forms![Form1](nameField).Text = "Message for `Form1`"
```

**Question.**
How to write the path to the form through a variable?
Those. replace `Forms! [Form1]` with a variable.
For example, something like:

```
   Dim nameForm  As String
    nameForm = "Form1"
    Forms![nameForm](nameField).Text = "Message for `Form1`"
```

Or something like:

```
   Dim nameForm  As String
    nameForm = "Form1"
    Forms(nameForm)(nameField).Text = "Message for `Form1`"
```

Or determine the active form and use it:

```
   Dim FormActiv As Form            
Set FormActiv = Screen.ActiveForm
nameForm.Name = FormActiv.Name

Forms![FormActiv](nameField).Text = "Message for `Form1`"
```

How to do it right?
Essence: I registered in one place the `name of the form` and use it in various procedures or in several places of the procedure.

Comment: [Forms]![FormName]![ControlName]. You should keep a copy of [this](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm).

Comment: @eusataf: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know which way is the best of them?

Comment: @UnhandledException `Gustav` answered my question.
I am currently testing its performance for my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:

```
Forms(nameForm)(nameField).Value = "Message for 'Form1'"
```